# AWS CDK event bridge and api gateway AWS example does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

I am following the instructions here to setup an event bridge: https://eventbus-cdk.workshop.aws/en/04-api-gateway-service-integrations/01-rest-api/rest-apis.html

Based on the error message, the error is coming from this line of code: languageResource.addMethod("POST", new apigw.Integration({

I am not sure what is causing this issue because this is an example given by AWS and should work, but it does not.

I can build it but it fails with the following error on cdk deploy:

```
CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::ApiGateway::Method           | MyRestAPI/Default/{language}/POST (MyRestAPIlanguagePOSTB787D51A) Invalid Resource identifier specified (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NotFoundException;
```

The code is below:

```
    const myLambda = new lambda.Function(this, "MyEventProcessor", {
  code: new lambda.InlineCode("def main(event, context):\n\tprint(event)\n\treturn {'statusCode': 200, 'body': 'Hello, World'}"),
  handler: "index.main",
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_7
})

  
const bus = new events.EventBus(this, `pwm-${this.stage}-MdpEventBus`)
new cdk.CfnOutput(this, "PwmMdpEventBus", {value: bus.eventBusName})

new events.Rule(this, `PwmMdpEventBusRule`, {
  eventBus: bus,
  eventPattern: {source: [`com.amazon.alexa.english`]},
  targets: [new targets.LambdaFunction(myLambda)]
})

const apigwRole = new iam.Role(this, "MYAPIGWRole", {
  assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal("apigateway"),
  inlinePolicies: {
    "putEvents": new iam.PolicyDocument({
      statements: [new iam.PolicyStatement({
        actions: ["events:PutEvents"],
        resources: [bus.eventBusArn]
      })]
    })
  }
});

const options = {
  credentialsRole: apigwRole,
  requestParameters: {
    "integration.request.header.X-Amz-Target": "'AWSEvents.PutEvents'",
    "integration.request.header.Content-Type": "'application/x-amz-json-1.1'"
  },
  requestTemplates: {
    "application/json": `#set($language=$input.params('language'))\n{"Entries": [{"Source": "com.amazon.alexa.$language", "Detail": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.body)", "Resources": ["resource1", "resource2"], "DetailType": "myDetailType", "EventBusName": "${bus.eventBusName}"}]}`
  },
  integrationResponses: [{
    statusCode: "200",
    responseTemplates: {
      "application/json": ""
    }
  }]
}

const myRestAPI = new apigw.RestApi(this, "MyRestAPI");

const languageResource = myRestAPI.root.addResource("{language}");

languageResource.addMethod("POST", new apigw.Integration({
  type: apigw.IntegrationType.AWS,
  uri: `arn:aws:apigateway:${cdk.Aws.REGION}:events:path//`,
  integrationHttpMethod: "POST",
  options: options,
}),
{
  methodResponses: [{
      statusCode: "200"
    }],
  requestModels: {"application/json": model.getModel(this, myRestAPI) },
  requestValidator: new apigw.RequestValidator(this, "myValidator", {
    restApi: myRestAPI,
    validateRequestBody: true
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In the AWS example, they are encapsulating your code inside

```
export class MyCdkAppStack extends cdk.Stack {
...
}
```

Are you missing that encapsulation? I noticed your sample code didn't include it. Because when you execute `const myRestAPI = new apigw.RestApi(this, "MyRestAPI");` the `this` should refer to the `MyCdkAppStack` instance.

Comment: Yes, I have this code:                                                                                                         
 export class CdkStack extends BaseStack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct) {
    super(scope);